# Установка дня недели в datapiker

Tags: jquery

Использую библиотеку jquery.daterangepicker.min.js, как установить дни недели с понедельника, а не с воскресения, как по умолчанию

```
$('#date-range1').dateRangePicker(
    {
    separator : ' до ',
    getValue: function()
    {
        if ($('#date-range200').val() && $('#date-range201').val() )
            return $('#date-range200').val() + ' до ' + $('#date-range201').val();
        else
            return '';
    },
    setValue: function(s,s1,s2)
    {
        $('#date-range200').val(s1);
        $('#date-range201').val(s2);
    }
});
```

Comment: если речь про http://www.daterangepicker.com/ , то необходимый параметр для стартового дня недели firstDay : для воскресения должно быть "firstDay": 0

Answer (score 0):

Используйте опцию firstDay :

`$('#date-range1').dateRangePicker({ firstDay: 1});`